# no changes after compiling

Tags: silverlight, xap

When I compile my Silverlight prjoect changes aren't made.
And when I create a new Project no xap file is generated. neither in clientbin nor bin debug/release.
I cleared cache ...I tried different browsers. Nothing works

Comment: You are going to have to provide a lot more detail than this. Try creating a new project that just displays one item - e.g. a TextBlock - and see if that works. If it does, compare that project with yours to see what the differences are.

Comment: I tried. it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out myself.
in vs2010 on options->projects and solutions->build and run->On run, when projects are out of date it was set to never build.

i have no idea how that was done because i never changed anything there.